# Hide a shipping method frontend and still show in backend condition based magento 2

Tags: customer, shipping-methods, magento-2.0.7

I want hide a multiple shipping method in frontend based on customer group.

Please tell me **Where I have to put the condition to check shipping method with customer group?**

If match then shipping method should be visible.

Can any one help me on this problem ? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if customer group is the desired one set collect rate function return empty

Answer (score 1):

Put the condition on shipping abstract method and check the condition with current shipping method

I hope it will help you.